# How can I transsmit an object as set Params to Derived Query Methods in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a Pojo (TomDto) in which the parameters are accumulated, according to which the native query is compiled.

```java
    @Query(value = """
            SELECT *
            FROM tom_schema.tom t
            WHERE t.title ILIKE LOWER(concat('%', :#{#tomDto.title}, '%'))
                AND
                  t.completed = :#{#tomDto.completed}
                AND
                  t.priority_id IS NULL
               OR t.priority_id = :#{#tomDto.priorityId}
                AND
                  t.category_id IS NULL
               OR t.category_id = :#{#tomDto.categoryId}
                AND
                  t.task_date IS NULL
               OR t.task_date BETWEEN cast(:#{#tomDto.dateFrom} as timestamp) 
                                         AND 
                                      cast(:#{#tomDto.dateTo} as timestamp)
                AND
                  t.user_id = :#{#tomDto.userId};
                            """, nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Tom> findWithMultiParam(TomDto tomDto, Pageable pageable);
```

But during the request I get an error:

```yaml
{
    "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Could not locate named parameter [__$synthetic$__7], expecting one of [__$synthetic$__4, __$synthetic$__3, __$synthetic$__6, __$synthetic$__5, __$synthetic$__7;, __$synthetic$__2, __$synthetic$__1]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [__$synthetic$__7], expecting one of [__$synthetic$__4, __$synthetic$__3, __$synthetic$__6, __$synthetic$__5, __$synthetic$__7;, __$synthetic$__2, __$synthetic$__1]"
}
```

Maybe there are ideas what the problem might be or you can rewrite the query, but only without using these parameters in the method parameters (5-6 parameters to specify in the method parameters is not convenient)?

Comment: As I know, when you are using "nativeQuery = true", hibernate wont try to translate your query or use the objects, it just populate the query string with parameters and execute it directly on database, so I don't think that it is possible to do what you are looking for.!! and you need to define parameters in method signature seperately

Answer (score 0):

```java
    @Query(value = """
            SELECT *
            FROM tom_schema.tom t\040
            WHERE t.title ILIKE LOWER(concat('%', :#{#tomDto.title}, '%'))\040
                AND\040
                  t.completed = :#{#tomDto.completed}\040
                AND\040
                  t.priority_id IS NULL\040
               OR t.priority_id = :#{#tomDto.priorityId}\040
                AND
                  t.category_id IS NULL
               OR t.category_id = :#{#tomDto.categoryId}\040
                AND\040
                  t.task_date IS NULL\040
               OR t.task_date BETWEEN cast(:#{#tomDto.dateFrom} as timestamp)\040\040
                                         AND\040\040
                                      cast(:#{#tomDto.dateTo} as timestamp)\040
                AND\040
                  t.user_id = :#{#tomDto.userId}\040
                            """, nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Tom> findWithMultiParam(TomDto tomDto, Pageable pageable);
```

It need to add :  **\040** (Trailing whitespaces inside text block )

I added more spaces, because when transferring lines, I may have forgotten to put a space between Sql statements.